# Extract Unique Time Slices in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I use Oracle 10g and I have a table that stores a snapshot of data on a person for a given day. Every night an outside process adds new rows to the table for any person whose had any changes to their core data (stored elsewhere). This allows a query to be written using a date to find out what a person 'looked' like on some past day. A new row is added to the table even if only a single aspect of the person has changed--the implication being that many columns have duplicate values from slice to slice since not every detail changed in each snapshot.

Below is a data sample:

```
SliceID  PersonID   StartDt  Detail1    Detail2  Detail3  Detail4 ...
      1       101  08/20/09      Red    Vanilla     N          23
      2       101  08/31/09   Orange  Chocolate     N          23
      3       101  09/15/09   Yellow  Chocolate     Y          24
      4       101  09/16/09    Green  Chocolate     N          24
      5       102  01/10/09     Blue      Lemon     N          36
      6       102  01/11/09   Indigo      Lemon     N          36
      7       102  02/02/09   Violet      Lemon     Y          36
      8       103  07/07/09      Red     Orange     N          12
      9       104  01/31/09   Orange     Orange     N          12
     10       104  10/20/09   Yellow     Orange     N          13
```

I need to write a query that pulls out time slices records where some pertinent bits, not the whole record, have changed. So, referring to the above, if I only want to know the slices in which Detail3 has changed from its previous value, then I would expect to only get rows having SliceID 1, 3 and 4 for PersonID 101 and SliceID 5 and 7 for PersonID 102 and SliceID 8 for PersonID 103 and SliceID 9 for PersonID 104.

I'm thinking I should be able to use some sort of Oracle Hierarchical Query (using CONNECT BY [PRIOR]) to get what I want, but I have not figured out how to write it yet. Perhaps YOU can help.

Thanks you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on the LAG() solution, which is basically the same as that of egorius, but I show my workings ;)

```
SQL> select * from
  2  (
  3      select sliceid
  4             , personid
  5             , startdt
  6             , detail3 as new_detail3
  7             ,  lag(detail3) over (partition by personid 
  8                                    order by startdt) prev_detail3
  9      from some_table
 10  )
 11  where prev_detail3 is null
 12  or ( prev_detail3 != new_detail3 )
 13  /

   SLICEID   PERSONID STARTDT   N P
---------- ---------- --------- - -
         1        101 20-AUG-09 N
         3        101 15-SEP-09 Y N
         4        101 16-SEP-09 N Y
         5        102 10-JAN-09 N
         7        102 02-FEB-09 Y N
         8        103 07-JUL-09 N
         9        104 31-JAN-09 N

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The point about this solution is that it hauls in results for 103 and 104, who don't have slice records where detail3 has changed.  If that is a problem we can apply an additional filtration, to return only rows with changes:

```
SQL> with subq as (
  2      select t.*
  3             , row_number () over (partition by personid
  4                                   order by sliceid ) rn
  5      from
  6          (
  7              select sliceid
  8                     , personid
  9                     , startdt
 10                     , detail3 as new_detail3
 11                     ,  lag(detail3) over (partition by personid
 12                                           order by startdt) prev_detail3
 13              from some_table
 14          ) t
 15      where t.prev_detail3 is null
 16      or ( t.prev_detail3 != t.new_detail3 )
 17       )
 18  select sliceid
 19         , personid
 20         , startdt
 21         , new_detail3
 22         , prev_detail3
 23  from subq sq
 24  where exists ( select null from subq x
 25                 where x.personid = sq.personid
 26                 and   x.rn > 1 )
 27  order by sliceid
 28  /

   SLICEID   PERSONID STARTDT   N P
---------- ---------- --------- - -
         1        101 20-AUG-09 N
         3        101 15-SEP-09 Y N
         4        101 16-SEP-09 N Y
         5        102 10-JAN-09 N
         7        102 02-FEB-09 Y N

SQL>
```

**edit**

As egorius points out in the comments, the OP *does* want hits for all users, even if they haven't changed, so the first version of the query is the correct solution.

Comment: Slowly getting closer and closer :)
Although daddy6Elbows says he wants SliceID 8 for PersonID 103 and SliceID 9 for PersonID 104.

Comment: Thanks. Everyone had good answers, but I've got to give the nod to the most complete one--including examples and extra commentary. But I gave everybody a point because they were all technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have better luck with the [LAG](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php) function:

```
SELECT s.sliceid
  FROM (SELECT t.sliceid,
               t.personid,
               t.detail3,
               LAG(t.detail3) OVER (PARTITION BY t.personid ORDER BY t.startdt) 'prev_val'
          FROM TABLE t) s
 WHERE s.personid = 101
   AND (s.prev_val IS NULL OR s.prev_val != s.detail3)
```

Subquery Factoring alternative:

```
WITH slices AS (
  SELECT t.sliceid,
         t.personid,
         t.detail3,
         LAG(t.detail3) OVER (PARTITION BY t.personid ORDER BY t.startdt) 'prev_val'
    FROM TABLE t)
SELECT s.sliceid
  FROM slices s
 WHERE s.personid = 101
   AND (s.prev_val IS NULL OR s.prev_val != s.detail3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to OMG Ponies' answer: if you need to query slices for all persons, you'll need `partition by`:

```
  SELECT s.sliceid
       , s.personid
    FROM (SELECT t.sliceid,
                 t.personid,
                 t.detail3,
                 LAG(t.detail3) OVER (
                   PARTITION BY t.personid ORDER BY t.startdt
                 ) prev_val
            FROM t) s
   WHERE (s.prev_val IS NULL OR s.prev_val != s.detail3)
```